WrongTypeOfReturnValue while using Mockito
I am trying to use Mockito to test but getting below error
org.mockito.exceptions,misusing,WrongTypeOfReturnValue
Here is the code I am using
BegeoRequest begeorequest1 = new BegeoRequest();

List<Map<String , object>> queryparam = new ArrayList<>();
List<BeGeo> list = new ARrayList<>();

Mockito.when(util.esutil.search(Begeo.class,Begeo_index,Begeo_index,queryparam)).thenReturn(list);


Is util.esutil.search a Mockito mock? It doesn't look like one. Where do you assign its value?

Voting to close, OP has not responded to request for clarification and with the missing info it is impossible to provide an answer.

Hi Sorry for Delayed response.
@knittl : I missed to add the util.sutil as a Mock due to which it was failing. Corrected and its working now

util.esutil is not a mock. You can only stub mocks (that includes spies). Trying to stub anything else will fail. Unfortunately, the error messages are quite confusing, because Mockito keeps an internal stack that gets out of sync with your code if you try to stub non-mock objects.
